# Difference between const char[] Variable; and "some chars"

Tags: c, xc8

I have code like this:

```
const char menu23[] = "2.3. ";
const char menu24[] = "2.4. ";   
const char menu25[] = "2.5. ";  
const char menu26[] = "2.6. "; 
const char menu27[] = "2.7. ";      
const char menu28[] = "2.8. ";  

MenuEntry menu[] = // MenuEntry is a struct
{
    {menu23,  MENU2_OPTIONS, 22, 24, 23,  0,  0,  0}, // 23
    {menu24,  MENU2_OPTIONS, 23, 25,  2,  0,  0,  0}, // 24
    {menu25,  MENU2_OPTIONS, 24, 26,  0,  0,  0,  0}, // 25
    {menu26,  MENU2_OPTIONS, 25, 27,  0,  0,  0,  0}, // 26
    {menu27,  MENU2_OPTIONS, 26, 28,  0,  0,  0,  0}, // 27
    {menu28,  MENU2_OPTIONS, 27, 29,  0,  0,  0,  0} // 28
}
```

Can I replace it with this?

```
MenuEntry menu[] = // MenuEntry is a struct
{
    {"2.3. ",  MENU2_OPTIONS, 22, 24, 23,  0,  0,  0}, // 23
    {"2.4. ",  MENU2_OPTIONS, 23, 25,  2,  0,  0,  0}, // 24
    {"2.5. ",  MENU2_OPTIONS, 24, 26,  0,  0,  0,  0}, // 25
    {"2.6. ",  MENU2_OPTIONS, 25, 27,  0,  0,  0,  0}, // 26
    {"2.7. ",  MENU2_OPTIONS, 26, 28,  0,  0,  0,  0}, // 27
    {"2.8. ",  MENU2_OPTIONS, 27, 29,  0,  0,  0,  0} // 28
}
```

Is there any functional difference?

Comment: It would help to show the definition of `MenuEntry`

Answer (score 2):

There is a **big** difference.

In this problem, first member of `MenuItem` must be `char *` type. (Otherwise first version of code in this question will fail with compile errors.)

`char menu23[] = "2.3. ";` This is a char array. String is stored in array's memory. Its lifetime is the same as array. If it's defined in a function, it will be destroyed after function returns. If it's defined as global variable, then there is no functional difference with second version. (But still different in implement perspective.)

`{"2.3. ",  MENU2_OPTIONS, 22, 24, 23,  0,  0,  0},` String in this line is a literal constant. It will be stored in memory's static area. Its lifetime will be the same as your application.

Answer (score 0):

No differences. The first, though, can be more flexible in case you want to change the name of each menu later on (and in case the constant names are used in multiple locations).

Comment: In general there are differences; if the struct in question had an array for first member then the second version would work but the first doesn't. (Since the first version works for OP we can infer that the struct has a `const char *` member)

Comment: @M.M Wrong. If first member of `MenuEntry` is char array, the second version doesn't work neither. Because char array can't be assigned with string literals. We must use something like `strcpy()` to do this. Otherwise there would be compile errors.

Comment: @MartinZhai string literals can initialize a char array, e.g `char x[4] = "abc";` . You are confusing initialization with assignment

Comment: @M.M Your code can work. But scenario in this question is assignment rather than initialization. A structure's member can only be initialized in its constructor.

Comment: @MartinZhai there are no constructors in C. `MenuEntry menu[] = {` indicates initailization. It declares `menu` and then provides initializers. Assignment statements do not declare anything.

Comment: @M.M My bad. You are right. First member of `MenuEntry` can be char array. If so, second version of code in this question should work. But first version will cause compile errors. So in fact, first member of `MenuEntry` must be a char pointer.